I want to find distinct values from a column in an Access (accdb) database table
I want to select all the rows in a database table where the values in FileSize are unique.
I am using .NET, OleDB, and SQL against an Access database:
ID  FileName    FileSize
------------------------
1   George.txt      84
2   Tom.txt         14
3   Henry.txt       14
4   Dick.txt        38
5   Harry.txc       20

I have tried variations of:
SELECT DISTINCT FileSize 
FROM DupTable 
WHERE COUNT(*) = 1;

This query throws this error:

Cannot have aggregate function in WHERE clause (COUNT(*)=1)

The query should return the rows with IDs 1, 4, 5 as those FileSize values are unique.
The FileSize of 14 is duplicated, and should be omitted from the result.
Can anyone suggest a SQL statement that would work for me?
Thank you!

For conditions on aggregations you use HAVING, not WHERE:
Select FileSize FROM DupTable 
GROUP BY FileSize
HAVING COUNT(*)=1

If you want the ID associated with those, you can use
Select MAX(ID) AS ID, FileSize FROM DupTable 
GROUP BY FileSize
HAVING COUNT(*)=1

Or get the whole record with a self-join
Select * FROM DupTable 
WHERE FileSize in (
  Select FileSize FROM DupTable 
  GROUP BY FileSize
  HAVING COUNT(*)=1
)


Seems like OP wants the whole rows, not just the filesize values.

Select MAX(ID) AS ID, FileSize FROM DupTable 
GROUP BY FileSize
HAVING COUNT(*)=1

gives error: Circular reference cause by alias 'ID' in query definition's SELECT list
But the but the last SQL:
Select * FROM DupTable
WHERE FileSize in (
Select FileSize FROM DupTable
GROUP BY FileSize
HAVING COUNT(*)=1
)
is giving me the results I needed.
Thank You for the SQL and also teaching me about HAVING/WHERE
